# How to add a skeleton load for generated items

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a slider of items similar to Netflix but with movies, using the info recovered from the tmdb API.

I would like to add a skeleton load for each dynamically generated item using map to improve the user experience.

First of all for the skeleton loading I got a lot of inspiration from this code available on pen code that I adapted afterwards.

https://codepen.io/mxbck/pen/EvmLVp

I try a solution first here but it does not work, I voluntarily remove code that did not relate to my problem for clarity:

Slider component

```
import React, {PureComponent , Component } from "react";
import style from './Caroussel.css';
import MovieItem from "../components/MovieItem";
import MovieItemContainer from '../components/MovieItem/MovieItemContainer';

class Slider extends Component {

   constructor(props){
       super(props);
       this.handleOnLeftArrowClick = this.leftArrowClick.bind(this);
       this.handleOnRightArrowClick = this.rightArrowClick.bind(this);

       this.state = {
          sliderItems: [],
       }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
       this.updateSliderState();
       this.setState({
           totalItems: this.props.movieList.length,
           sliderItem: this.props.movieList
       })
     }

    componentWillMount(){
       if(typeof(window) !== 'undefined') {
         $(window).on('resize', this.updateSliderState.bind(this))
       }
    }

    render(){

        const { sliderItem} = this.state;

        const sliderClass = cx ({
            sliderMask:true,
            moving
        })

       return(
          <div className="wrapper">
             <div className={style.slider}>
                <div className={sliderClass} ref="slider">
                 {this.state.sliderItem ? 
                     sliderItem.map((element, index) => (
                         <MovieItemContainer>
                             <MovieItem 
                                 key={index}
                                 title={element.title}
                                 id={element.id}
                                 release_date={element.release_date}
                                 url={element.backdrop_path} 
                              />
                         </MovieItemContainer>
                     ))
                     :
                     sliderItem.map((element, index) => {
                         null
                     })
                  }

                </div>
                {
                  click &&
                    <div className={style.leftArrow} ref="leftArrow">
                        <IosArrowBack onClick{this.handleOnLeftArrowClick} color="black" />
                    </div>
                }
                    <div className={style.rightArrow} ref="rightArrow">
                        <IosArrowForward onClick={this.handleOnRightArrowClick} color="black" />
                   </div>
             </div>
         </div>
      );
    }
  }

  export default Slider;
```

MovieItem Container component

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import '../../../style/card.scss';

class MovieItemContainer extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div className="card">
             {this.props.children}
        </div>
      );
   }
 }

 export default MovieItemContainer;
```

MovieItem component

```
 import React from 'react';
 import Moment from 'react-moment';
 import style from './MovieItem.css';
 import {Link} from 'react-router';

 const MovieItem  = ({ url, title, release_date, id }) => {
      let link ='https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/'+url;

      const text_truncate = (str, length, ending) => {
          if (length == null) {
               length = 100;
          }
          if (ending == null) {
               ending = '...';
          }
          if (str.length > length) {
              return str.substring(0, length - ending.length) + ending;
          } else {
              return str;
          }
       };

       return (
          <div className={style.sliderItem}>
               <div style={{ borderBottomLeftRadius: 8, borderBottomRightRadius:8 }} className={style.sliderItemInner}>
                <img style={{ borderRadius: 8 }} className={style.cover} src={link} />
                <div className={style.shadow}></div>
                    <div className={style.titles}>
                        <span className={style.title}>
                            <Link className={style.title} to={`film/${id}`}>
                                {text_truncate(title,18)}
                            </Link>
                        </span>
                        <span className={style.release_date}>
                            <Moment format="YYYY">   
                                {release_date}       
                            </Moment>
                        </span> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          )
        }

  export default MovieItem;
```

The MovieItem component only makes the item a movie with a background image, the title of the movie and the year of release.

In the example above, the loading is done for only one card, I would just adapt this code for each of the generated items (10 items).

I thank you in advance for your help and your answers.

Comment: can you add MovieItem  component code.

Comment: Hello, I just put the post with the component code MovieItem